Brownian Motion / heat flow generated by Hodge Laplacian
Let $\square_M = - (dd^* + d^*d)$ be the Hodge Laplacian on the differential forms $\Omega(M)$ (or if you wish, on a fixed $\Omega^k(M)$). What is the stochastic process generated by this operator? What is its state space and how can we imagine it? Does it satisfy a nice SDE like $dU_t = H_i(U_t) \circ dW_t^i$ for a horizontal BM $U$? Also, what would the heat flow (below) here really mean?
For example, I would expect that its transition kernel is given by the heat kernel $p_t$, i.e. the fundamental solution of $\frac{d}{dt} \theta = \square_M \theta$. I found that for all $t$, $p_t$ is a section of $\Omega(M) \boxtimes \Omega(M)^*$, the exterior tensor product, i.e. for all $x,y \in M$, $$p_t(x,y) \in  \Omega(M)_x \otimes (\Omega(M))_y^* \simeq \text{Hom}\left(\Omega(M))_y, (\Omega(M))_x\right).$$ Now a guess would be that this means instead of a heat transition density from $x$ to $y \in M$ as is the case for the known Brownian Motion on $M$ generated by the Laplace-Beltrami $\Delta_M$ on functions, here, this is a transition density from one fiber to another. I.e. heat is stored as kind of matrices/multivectors (values of differential forms at that point) in the fibers. Just confusing here is that the fiber at $y$ gets mapped to that at $x$ instead of the other way around.
Finally, from Chapter 7 in Hsu's famous book (why this question also originated) it seems that the Weitzenböck formula is used to relate the Hodge Laplacian to the connection Laplacian plus a potential which seems practical because the connection Laplacian, at least on functions, generates the old Brownian motion on $M$. Hsu arrives at a Feynman-Kac formula for the heat equation, $\theta(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_x [U_0 M_t U_t^{-1} \theta_0(X_t) ]$ for $X_t$ a usual Brownian Motion on $M$ and $U_t$ its horizontal lift, and $M_t$ some functional. This looks promising, but also here we don't have a naively desired $\mathbb{E}_x [\theta_0(Y_t)]$, so not one clear process. (The latter can of course not happen since $\theta_0$ is not a real-valued function anymore. So probably the Feynman-Kac formula for $\theta$ is the closest one can get to that...)
A striking unfamiliarity is the fact that $\square_M$, the generator of the heat flow and wished stochastic process, does not act on functions from the state space $M \to \mathbb{R}$ anymore, but on forms $M \to \Lambda^kT^*M$. I have never dealt with such a case.
Remark:

A nice insight for the connection Laplacian is given here.
Of course the question could be equally posed for a "Laplacian-like" differential operator on a vector bundle satisfying a Weitzenböck like formula. Maybe for the special case of differential forms a bit more insight is possible...

